# How to set PyQt element text from another running script?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyqt, python-multithreading, pyqt6

I have a client socket program and a server socket program in python. The client sends a message and the server echos the message as well as stores some variables about the clients ip and port number.

I made a GUI in PyQt with some text fields to store the clients ip and port number.

The problem is I need to run both the server socket python file and the PyQt GUI at the same time, as well as update the GUI's text fields from the variables in the server socket file(client ip and port number).

I have tried creating a new thread in the server socket file right before the server accepts clients which does start the gui and lets the server run. But when the code to set the client ip and port for the gui gets executed I get an error `AttributeError: 'Ui_MainWindow' object has no attribute 'client_ip'.`

gui.py

```
from PyQt6 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets


class Ui_MainWindow(object):
    def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
        MainWindow.setObjectName("MainWindow")
        MainWindow.resize(800, 600)

        self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(MainWindow)
        self.centralwidget.setObjectName("centralwidget")

        self.label = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.label.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(170, 150, 66, 18))
        self.label.setObjectName("label")

        self.label_2 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.label_2.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(460, 150, 81, 18))
        self.label_2.setObjectName("label_2")

        # CLIENT IP
        self.client_ip = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.client_ip.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(250, 150, 66, 18))
        self.client_ip.setText("")
        self.client_ip.setObjectName("client_ip")

        # CLIENT PORT
        self.client_port = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.client_port.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(560, 150, 66, 18))
        self.client_port.setText("")
        self.client_port.setObjectName("client_port")

        MainWindow.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.menubar = QtWidgets.QMenuBar(MainWindow)
        self.menubar.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 0, 800, 28))
        self.menubar.setObjectName("menubar")

        MainWindow.setMenuBar(self.menubar)
        self.statusbar = QtWidgets.QStatusBar(MainWindow)
        self.statusbar.setObjectName("statusbar")
        MainWindow.setStatusBar(self.statusbar)

        self.retranslateUi(MainWindow)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(MainWindow)

    def retranslateUi(self, MainWindow):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        MainWindow.setWindowTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "MainWindow"))
        self.label.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Client IP:"))
        self.label_2.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Client Port:"))

    def set_client_ip(self, ip):
        self.client_ip.setText(ip)

    def set_client_port(self, port):
        self.client_port.setText(port)

    def main(self):
        import sys
        app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
        MainWindow = QtWidgets.QMainWindow()
        ui = Ui_MainWindow()
        ui.setupUi(MainWindow)
        MainWindow.show()
        sys.exit(app.exec())
```

server.py

```
import socket
from myUtils import add_arguments
from gui import Ui_MainWindow
from threading import Thread


def handle_client(client_socket, client_address, gui):
    """
    Handles the client, receives and sends ack back

    :param client_socket: client socket
    :param client_address: client IP address
    :return:
    """

    print(f"[+] Connected to Client: {client_address[0]} PORT: {address[1]}")

    try:

        # SET GUI CLIENT IP AND PORT
        client_ip = client_address[0]
        client_port = client_address[1]
        gui.set_client_ip(client_ip)
        gui.set_client_port(client_port)


        with client_socket:

            client_data = client_socket.recv(1024).decode()

            while client_data:
                print(f"[+] From: {client_address[0]}: {client_data}")
                response = f"from server: {len(client_data)}".encode()
                client_socket.send(response)
                client_data = client_socket.recv(1024).decode()

    except ConnectionResetError:
        print(f"[-] Closing connection to client: {client_address[0]}")
        client_socket.close()


if __name__ == '__main__':

    gui = Ui_MainWindow()
    gui_thread = Thread(target=gui.main)
    gui_thread.start()

    # DEFAULTS
    PORT = 65002
    HOST = '0.0.0.0'

    args = add_arguments("Start the server",
                         ['-p'],
                         ['--port'],
                         [int],
                         ['?'],
                         [False],
                         ["The port number."])

    if args.port:
        PORT = args.port

    try:

        with socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM) as s:

            s.bind((HOST, PORT))
            s.listen()
            print(f"===== Server started on HOST: {HOST}\tPORT: {PORT} =====")

            while True:
                connection, address = s.accept()
                handle_client(connection, address, gui)

    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        print("Caught keyboard interrupt, exiting.")
```

Comment: No. The QApplication and any UI element *must* be in the main thread, anything else is in other threads. Use QThread subclasses and custom signals, and also don't modify pyuic files (as clearly written in their headers), but follow the official guidelines about [using Designer](//www.riverbankcomputing.com/static/Docs/PyQt5/designer.html) instead.

Comment: Using QThread worked. Thanks for the tip about not modifying the ui file, going to separate the logic out and extend from that file.

Answer (score 0):

[musicamantes advice](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74504651/how-to-set-pyqt-element-text-from-another-running-script/74505773#comment131519879_74504651) worked:

> The QApplication and any UI element must be in the main thread, anything else is in other threads. Use QThread subclasses and custom signals, and also don't modify pyuic files (as clearly written in their headers), but follow the official guidelines about using [Designer](https://www.riverbankcomputing.com/static/Docs/PyQt5/designer.html) instead.

I used QThread to start a worker thread that runs my socket script.